# writing crawling image with name to local server with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler

i am making a web crawler and i want to save my images in image directory of my project with their original name... let suppose after crawling i get two image where first time i get../logo.png and other time i get another image with .../glasses.png title name then i want to save my image as same title in my image folder
here is my code:

```
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var title = $('head title').text();
    var keywords = $('head meta[name=keywords]').attr('content');
    var desc = $('head meta[name=description]').attr('content');
    var links = $('a');
    var img = $('img').attr('src');
    var request = http.get($, function(res){
        var imagedata = ''
        res.setEncoding('binary')

        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            imagedata += chunk
        });

        res.on('end', function(){

            fs.writeFile(img, imagedata, 'binary', function(err){
                if (err) throw err
                console.log('File saved.')
            });
        });

    });
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: `http.get($, function(res){...` Shouldn't `$` be `img`(the src attribute's value);

Comment: soo then what i write insted of $ ? please explain @c.p.u1

Comment: Bro, you're trying to http.get all images, right? You need to `http.request` for the img attribute's src value. Right now, you are sending a request to the object returned by `cheerio.load`. `var request = http.get($, function(res){` should be `var request = http.get(img, function(res){` where img is the src value.

Comment: ok itswork .but i have done some changes i take image in array but error is split is not define  soo what can i use???